# "NoClassDefFoundError" in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, neo4j, m2eclipse

I am attempting to create a server plugin by following this tutorial http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html

i've created a maven project (following this tutorial http://blog.neo4j.org/2012/03/how-to-set-up-maven-project-with-neo4j.html) in eclipse and added the necessary dependencies from the maven repository, which i saw actually in the pom.xml and in the list of maven dependencies, and then i created my jar using the goal "clean install" and added it to neo4j plugins.

The latter plugin has been correctly added and i could check that thanks to :

```
curl -v http://localhost:7474/db/data/
```

but what is strange, is that i am getting the error below when i try to run it from the shell :

I am sure that the dependencies were really added when the jar was created ( i checked this using : mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose and **the package "org.lucene.lucene-spellchecker" containing this class was added as well**)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you

---

**dependency tree:**

```
[INFO] org.neo4j.server.plugin.custom:neo4j-didYouMean-plugin:jar:1.9.M05
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:neo4j:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.5.0:compile - omitted for     duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-udc:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j:neo4j-cypher:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.10.0:compile  
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-lucene-index:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-matching:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for  duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-graph-algo:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap- lru:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.neo4j:neo4j-jmx:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] +- org.neo4j:server-api:jar:1.9.M05:compile
[INFO] |  +- (org.neo4j:neo4j-kernel:jar:1.9.M05:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.neo4j.3rdparty.javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.2.r612:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile 
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spellchecker:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.5.0:compile  
[INFO]    \- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.5.0:compile
[INFO]       \- (org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.5.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

**error:**

```
 curl -X POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/ext/DidYouMeanPlugin/graphdb/didYouMean -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"query":"san francisco", "searchType":"airports" , "max":10}'

{
  "message" : "org/apache/lucene/search/spell/LevensteinDistance",
  "exception" : "NoClassDefFoundError",
  "fullname" : "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError",
  "stacktrace" : [    
           "org.neo4j.server.plugin.didYouMean.DidYouMeanPlugin.didYouMean(DidYouMeanPlugin.java:39)",   "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:168)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:300)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:122)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ccan you check the jar file with `jar tf file` if the lucene class is really in there?

Did you create it with mvn assembly single?

What you can also do is to use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` and copy those additional jar files into the plugins folder of your sever installation.

Comment: Many thanks Michael !
i used clean install assembly:single goal and it worked